# Flask (Jinja2) caching templates?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have some strange problem with HTML forms in Flask (Jinja2) templates. I have a form to create users in which the password field (HTML input type text, not password) is pre-filled with a random password. If I reload the page the password stays the same unless I reload the http server (same problem with WSGI under Apache). It is not a browser caching problem, all the meta tags and http headers are in place for that.

Maybe important to know, the input fields are code generated and inserted into the template like {{ elements.password | safe }}.

Thanks,
D

And the code:

util.py -> code to generate random passwords

```
def random_password(length=8):
    chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase
    password = ''
    for i in range(length):
        password += chars[ord(urandom(1)) % len(chars)]
    return password
```

add.py -> file that stores the form fields as a dict

```
"password": {
    "id": "password",
    "tag": {
        "type": "text",
        "value": util.random_password(),
    },
    "label": "Initial password",
    "help": None
},
```

form.py -> generates the HTML to pass to the template

```
def gen_html(self):

    for k, v in self.tags.items():

        h = self.base_element.replace('[LABEL]', v['label'])
        tag = ''
        value = v['tag']['value']

        if k in self.request_data:
            value = self.request_data[k]

        if v['tag']['type'] == 'text':
            tag = self.tag_skeletons['text'] % (v['id'], v['id'], value)

        elif v['tag']['type'] == 'select':
            options = ''
            tag = self.tag_skeletons['select'] % (v['id'], v['id'])

            if v['tag']['options']['empty_first']:
                options += '<option value=""></option>\n'

            for r in v['tag']['options']['data']:
                option = '<option value="%s">%s</option>\n'

                if value == r[v['tag']['options']['value_field']]:
                    option = '<option value="%s" selected="true">%s</option>\n'

                options += option % (r[v['tag']['options']['value_field']],
                                     r[v['tag']['options']['label_field']])

            tag = tag.replace('[OPTIONS]', options)

        elif v['tag']['type'] == 'email':
            tag = self.tag_skeletons['email'] % (v['id'], v['id'], value)

        elif v['tag']['type'] == 'password':
            tag = self.tag_skeletons['password'] % (v['id'], v['id'])

        h = h.replace('[FORM ELEMENT]', tag)

        # Show or remove error information
        if k in self.errors:
            h = h.replace('[ERROR INFO]', self.errors[k][1])
        else:
            pattern = re.compile(r'<div class="form-error">.*?</div>', re.DOTALL)
            h = pattern.sub('', h)

        self.html[k] = h
```

Comment: You need to provide the code in question.

Comment: Almost certainly because add.py contains a single static dictionary and so the value is generated *once* when the dictionary is first imported and never re-generated.

Comment: Also worth noting - Flask has a template system and there are *several* form handling libraries out there for Python (WTForms for Flask has a pretty nice integration but there are others).  You may already know that and are re-inventing the wheel for learning purposes or some other reason, but in case you *don't* ;-)

Comment: Thanks Sean, indeed a static dictionary problem, solved now. And I know there are libraries out there for form handling but for this app I want to have full control because things are going to get really complicated.